# ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutParams

Tags: android

I am trying to detect wheither a view is currently visible within a recycle view. Using Layout manager's [isViewPartiallyVisible](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#isViewPartiallyVisible(android.view.View,%20boolean,%20boolean)) method, I can pass a view in and see if it's partially visible. When I pass a [Textview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) into the method, I get a class cast exception:
`android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutParams`

So I changed Textview to [AppCompatTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatTextView.html) in all references and within the xml layout to match the library version to recycleviews. I am still getting the same error.

edit --- here's the calling method

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView    
....
private fun withinView(wk_predictionTV: WeakReference<AppCompatTextView>, recyclerView: RecyclerView): Boolean {
        try {
            return recyclerView.layoutManager.isViewPartiallyVisible(predictionTV.get()!!, false, true)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.e("Failed:${e.printStackTrace()}")
        }
        return true
    }
```

list_view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/train_list_filter_edtext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:hint="Enter Station Name"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.github.captain_miao.optroundcardview.OptRoundCardView
            android:id="@+id/top_card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/trainlist_side_margins"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/trainlist_side_margins"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/trainlist_card_margins"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            app:optRoundCardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:optRoundCardLeftBottomCorner="false"
            app:optRoundCardLeftTopCorner="true"
            app:optRoundCardRightBottomCorner="false"
            app:optRoundCardRightTopCorner="true"
            >

            ..
        </com.github.captain_miao.optroundcardview.OptRoundCardView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: is there any specific reason why you wanna use isViewPartiallyVisible instead of isVisible ?? and post your **method** code please

Comment: I am doing some calculation within the view and I want to it start as soon as the view edges come on display. IsVisible method returns true when the whole view is in display as I understand it.

Comment: It's nothing to do with the type of `TextView`. The problem is that `isViewPartiallyVisible()` only works with direct children of the `RecyclerView`. That is, the root `View` in your item layout. The `TextView` you're passing that method is apparently not the root `View`, but rather inside a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: What `isVisible` method are you talking about? How would I go about checking if the view is available within the linear layout?